# Trying to serve Index.html in ASP.NET Core project and /api/values elsewhere

Tags: asp.net-core, asp-net-core-spa-services

I've got a SPA app that I've loaded into my /wwwroot directory and it has an index.html file that I want loaded by default.  I then want the normal controller files to work.  That is the default values controller should run.  Below is my startup.  It does render wwwroot/index.html but then /api/values does not work (unless I comment out UseStaticFiles, then index.html does not).

How can I get both index.html to load and also the values controller to work.

startup.cs

```
public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
        options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
        options.DefaultFileNames.Add("index.html");
        app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

the values controller...

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work. As a quick test, did you try creating a new ASP.NET project and plugging in both index.html and that particular Configure() method?

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to solve my problem.

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
        options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
        options.DefaultFileNames.Add("index.html");


        app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

To test it I added `wwwroot/index.html` and a simple `/home/contact` controller and view class (no `/home/index` controller or view).