# Asp.net core web api show page

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a backend api for my mobile app on a `Asp.net Core web Api` project.

I will need to show two `HTML` pages in the same webapi project. Is it possible to have HTML pages in web api project?
And if yes how?

Comment: Could this be what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144536/trying-to-serve-index-html-in-asp-net-core-project-and-api-values-elsewhere

Answer (score 11):

Before using html with web api,you need to configure:

1.Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    //Configure the app to serve static files and enable default file mapping. 
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

2.Create a `wwwroot` folder in your Web Api project root and Create a js folder inside of the `wwwroot` folder.Finally add `Index.html`:

[image]

Here is a working demo about Web Api with Html page:

1.Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2.Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestsController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/Tests
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Test> GetTest()
    {
        var model = new List<Test>() { 
        new Test(){Id=1,Name="aaa"},
        new Test(){Id=2,Name="bbb"}
        };
        return model;
    }
```

3.Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="todos"></tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        getItems();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

4.site.js:

```
const uri = 'api/Tests';
let todos = [];

function getItems() {
    fetch(uri)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => _displayItems(data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Unable to get items.', error));
}
function _displayItems(data) {
    const tBody = document.getElementById('todos');
    tBody.innerHTML = '';
    data.forEach(item => {
        let tr = tBody.insertRow();
        let td1 = tr.insertCell(0);
        let textNode1 = document.createTextNode(item.id);
        td1.appendChild(textNode1);

        let td2 = tr.insertCell(1);
        let textNode2 = document.createTextNode(item.name);
        td2.appendChild(textNode2);


    });

    todos = data;
}
```

Reference:
[Call an ASP.NET Core web API with JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

Steps for example for Api Core project:

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` package
2. In `Startup.cs` in `ConfigureServices` method, change services.AddControllers() to `services.AddControllersWithViews();`
3. Add new Controller like this:

   ```
   [Route("Default")]
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       [Route("DownloadApp")]
       public IActionResult DownloadApp()
       {
           //you code here
           return View();
       }

       [Route("ResetPassword")]
       public IActionResult ResetPassword()
       {
          //you code here
          return View("Index");
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add your Views `DownloadApp.cshtml` and `ResetPassword.cshtml` to `Views/Home` folder.

Now you can see your page by following urls: Default/ResetPassword and Default/DownloadApp